# Linq Select: Using a value from a list if available

Tags: c#, linq

I am going to use some basic stripped down examples to illustrate my problem.

I have a class:

```
class Item
{
   int ID;
   bool Selected;
}
```

Now lets say I have two lists of the `Item` class:

```
List<Item> ListA = GetListA();
List<Item> ListB = GetListB();
```

Now I want to create a third list that has all the items from `ListB`. The important thing is that if a match (same `ID`) if found in `ListA` then I want to use that `Selected` value, otherwise I want to keep the `Selected` value of the item that is in `ListB`.

I am creating the third list as follows:

```
List<Item> ListC = from item in ListB 
select new Item
{
   ID = item.ID,
   Selected = item.Selected// <-- should use value form ListA if available
};
```

**Important**: I don't want to seem ignorant, but I **do not** want to change the way `ListC` is created. By that I mean I want to use the "linq select" method, and I want to use a "one liner" that assigns the `Selected` value... I know there are other ways to create the list which will work just fine, but then I won't learn anything new.

---

I have tried a couple of things so far...

I know this will work, but I don't want to query `ListA` twice:

```
Selected = ListA.Any(x => x.ID == item.ID) ? ListA.First(x => x.ID == item.ID).Selected : item.Selected
```

and I also tried using `DeafultIfEmpty` but I don't think that is the right think for this situation... because it didn't work, and it seems it is more use if `ListA` was empty (which I don't care about)

Comment: So many restrictions on solution method....

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ: True, but if I wasn't this specific then it would likely be a "bad" question, or a "duplicate". As I said, I already know of completely alternative approaches, but this specific one is what I wanted to work out

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can modify your last line of code as follows:

```
Selected = (ListA.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == item.ID) ?? item).Selected;
```

For `DefaultIfEmpty`, you'd have to do

```
Selected = ListA.Where(x => x.ID == item.ID).DefaultIfEmpty(item)
                                                       .First().Selected;
```

which is harder to follow but does essentially the same thing.

As Dominic has noted below, if you use `SingleOrDefault/Single` in place of `FirstOrDefault/First`, you will get an exception if you find two items in `ListA` with the same `ID` - which may be a check you want to introduce.

(There *are* better/more efficient ways of doing this, but as you say, you want to fix *this* way of doing it, not use a totally different way.)

Comment: Consider using `SingleOrDefault` if the `ID`s are unique instead of `FirstOrDefault`. Also, instead of `(ListA.Where(x => x.ID == item.ID).DefaultIfEmpty().First()
    ?? item).Selected`, you could simply use `ListA.Where(x => x.ID == item.ID).DefaultIfEmpty(item).First().Selected` (or `Single()`).

Comment: But I don't think you can get *nicer* than your first piece of code.

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for thanks. I thought about the `??` and also thought about some sort of encapsulation/scoping (whatever the correct term is), but it just didn't "click" to use a combination like what you have suggested

Answer (score 2):

What about this?

```
var query = from b in ListB
        join a in ListA
            on b.ID equals a.ID into g
        from r in g.DefaultIfEmpty(b)
        select new Item { ID = b.ID, Selected = r.Selected };
```

Comment: This may work, I don't know, but I am struggling to understand the logic of the join? Could you expand on your example and explain how/why it works?

Comment: This is left join. "g" is joined collection. If there is corresponding element in listA it is taken, if not is taken element from b (`g.DefaultIfEmpty(b)`)...

Comment: But in my case, there will always be an element in A. But if a match is in B, then that `Selected` value should be used instead. Maybe I just misunderstood your explanation?

Comment: The keyword is **"corresponding"**.

Comment: yeah, but I want ListB element to take priority

Comment: The important thing is that if a match (same ID) if found in ListA then **I want to use that Selected**. What about this?

Comment: haha... sorry, I got completely lost with my own example. You are correct. I was getting the lists the wrong way around (shameface)